# Wrap text with CDATA in XML

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a template that produces XML. Something like:

```
<items>
    <item th:each="itemEntry: ${rs1}">
        <name th:text="${itemEntry.value['ITEM_NAME']}"></name>
    </item>
</items>
```

What would I have to do to wrap the text of element name in CDATA, so that the result would be:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <name><![CDATA[My text]]></name>
    </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it was quite simple. I had to create my own dialect:

```
public class KovicaDialect extends AbstractDialect implements IExpressionObjectDialect {
    private static final XMLExpressionObjectFactory xmlExpressionObjectFactory = new XMLExpressionObjectFactory();

    public KovicaDialect() {
        super("kovica");
    }

    @Override
    public IExpressionObjectFactory getExpressionObjectFactory() {
        return xmlExpressionObjectFactory;
    }
}
```

The expression object factory looks like this:

```
public class XMLExpressionObjectFactory implements IExpressionObjectFactory {
    private static final String EXPRESSION_OBJECT_PREFIX = "xml";
    private static final Set<String> EXPRESSION_OBJECT_NAMES = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet(Arrays.asList(EXPRESSION_OBJECT_PREFIX)));

    @Override
    public Set<String> getAllExpressionObjectNames() {
        return EXPRESSION_OBJECT_NAMES;
    }

    @Override
    public Object buildObject(IExpressionContext context, String expressionObjectName) {
        if (expressionObjectName.equals(EXPRESSION_OBJECT_PREFIX) == true) {
            return new XMLUtils();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCacheable(String expressionObjectName) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the util class:

```
public class XMLUtils {
    public String cdata(String str) {
        String returnString = null;

        if (str != null) {
            returnString = "<![CDATA[" + str + "]]>";
        }

        return returnString;
    }
}
```

You have to set this dialect:

```
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine templateEngine = new org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.addDialect(new KovicaDialect());
```

then you can use it like this (it has to be an `th:utext`):

```
<name th:utext="${#xml.cdata(itemEntry.value['ITEM_NAMESMALL'])}"></name>
```